# vowpal wabbit installation make file

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am having a hard time installing vowpal wabbit.

The problem I run into is after cloning vw, when I run the command make.  Error message below

Would highly appreciate any help!
OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit
Thanks

A

```
$ make
Making all in vowpalwabbit
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Alejandro/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Alejandro/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/include          
-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG    - 
 Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -MT global_data.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/global_data.Tpo -c -o     global_data.lo global_data.cc
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/include -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -          ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -MT global_data.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/global_data.Tpo -c global_data.cc  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/global_data.o
In file included from comp_io.h:7:0,
             from global_data.h:17,
             from global_data.cc:13:
io_buf.h: In member function 'virtual int io_buf::open_file(const char*, bool, int)':
io_buf.h:72:25: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope ret = fileno(stdin);                         

In file included from global_data.h:17:0,
             from global_data.cc:13:
comp_io.h: In member function 'virtual int comp_io_buf::open_file(const char*, bool, int)':
comp_io.h:28:34: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
fil = gzdopen(fileno(stdin), "rb");
                              ^
global_data.cc: In constructor 'vw::vw()':
global_data.cc:295:32: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
stdout_fileno = fileno(stdout);
                            ^
Makefile:619: recipe for target 'global_data.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [global_data.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Alejandro/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
Makefile:390: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Alejandro/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
Makefile:503: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: I believe that to build on Windows, you need to have Visual Studio from Microsoft.  In the past some people managed to build vw with cygwin and a GNU/free toolset, but I'm not sure if it was trivial and whether this is still true.  See `README.windows.txt` in the source tree to build with Visual studio.  Another possible avenue is to have a linux VM on windows and use a straightforward linux `make` in it.

Comment: I'm also trying to compile VW right now (using Cygwin on Windows 8.1 64 Bit) and I'm getting the same error. I'm following the instructions from [here](http://mlwave.com/install-vowpal-wabbit-on-windows-and-cygwin/). I totally forgot how much I hate C++ thanks to .NET an its cozy ecosystem. I'll get back if I find a way to fix this...

Comment: I give up.. I fixed the fileno(...) errors but then new errors popped up, like undeclared alloca (which I fixed also) and then undeclared to_string (which I seem to be unable to fix). I guess I'll use the binary you linked below (it's a bit outdated though) or just start a Linux machine on Azure. ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the issue, but at least I can point you to a vowpalwabbit executable file.  So you do not have to make it.

https://github.com/MLWave/vowpal-wabbit-cygwin-executables

A noble soul from Kaggle pointed me to this link.  You need to install Cycwin and execute the .exe from cygwin.

There is also a pure Windows executable build https://github.com/MLWave/Kaggle_Rotten_Tomatoes

Also provided by Triskelion, the same folk who provided the build above.  His advice: To run that use "cmd" to open a console, don't click on the file.